# Асинхронность/многопоточность на сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, flask, асинхронность

Возникла необходимость на сервере реализовать асинхронную или многопоточную функцию. А именно, по приходящему запросу от клиента запускается цикл, который будет работать до тех пор, пока от этого же клиента не придёт следующий запрос на завершения работы цикла. Сначала я искал какое-нибудь готовое решение, вроде AIOHTTP, но так как решить задачу нужно было как можно быстрее, реализовал связку Flask(его я немного знаю) + threading. Чтобы было понятно, чего я пытаюсь добиться, приведу пример:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Функция, которая будет работать в потоке
def loop(): 
    try:
        print('Запуск потока')
        while flag == True:
            print('Производятся расчёты')
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        print('Поток завершён')
    
# По данному запросу запускаем функцию 
@app.route('/start')  
def start():
    global flag, thread
    flag = True
    print('Вы вызвали поток')
    thread = Thread(target=loop)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()   
    return 'start'

# Завершаем работу функции 
@app.route('/stop')
def stop():
    global flag
    flag = False
    thread.join()
    print('Вы завершили поток')  
    return 'stop'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Теперь, когда есть время разобраться, хотелось бы узнать, как можно реализовать этот же функционал, но с правильным подходом и какой фрейморк/библиотеку для этого выбрать?